# Unable to parse JSON list in Azure Data Factory ADF

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

In my datafactory pipeline I hava a web activity which is giving below JSON response. In the next stored procedure activity I am unable parse the output parameter. I tried few methods.

I have set Content-Type `application/json` in web activity

Sample JSON:

```
Output
{
    "Response": "[{\"Message\":\"Number of barcode(s) found:1\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"CCS Office\":[{\"Name\":\"Woodstock\",\"CCS Description\":null,\"BranchType\":\"Sub CFS Office\",\"Status\":\"Active\",\"Circle\":\"NJ\"}]}]"
}
```

For parameter in stored procedure activity:

```
@json(first(activity('Web1').output.Response))
```

output - System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

```
@json(activity('Web1').output.Response[0])
```

output - cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'

```
@json(activity('Web1').output.Response.Message)
```

output - cannot be evaluated because property 'Message' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'

Comment: Hello. Have you tried `.output.value[0].Message`, `.output.value[0].Response.Message` or `.output.value[0].Response` ? We are using this format and it works in our pipeline.

Comment: @Praetorian1995 I tired but it didn't work. Error -
activity('Web1').output.value[0].Message' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'Response'
'activity('Web1').output.value[0].Response.Message' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'Response'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:
I created a new pipeline, and created a parameter of type 'object' using your 'output' in its entirety:

```
{     "Response": "[{\"Message\":\"Number of barcode(s) found:1\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"CCS Office\":[{\"Name\":\"Woodstock\",\"CCS Description\":null,\"BranchType\":\"Sub CFS Office\",\"Status\":\"Active\",\"Circle\":\"NJ\"}]}]" }
```

I created a variable and setVariable activity.  Variable is of type string.  The dynamic expression I used is:

```
@{json(pipeline().parameters.output.response)[0]}
```

Let me break down and explain.  The {curly braces} were necessary because variable is of type string.  You may not want/need them.

```
json(....)
```

was necessary because data type for the value of 'response' was left as a string.  Whether it being string is correct behavior or not is a different discussion.  By converting from string to json, I can now do the final piece.

```
[0]
```

Now works because Data Factory sees the contents as an objects rather than string literal.  This conversion seems to have been applied to the nested contents as well, because without the encapsulating {curly braces} to convert to string, I would get a type error from my setVariable activity, as the variable is of type string.

Entire pipeline code:

```
{
"name": "pipeline11",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Set Variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "thing",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@{json(pipeline().parameters.output.response)[0]}",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "output": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "Response": "[{\"Message\":\"Number of barcode(s) found:1\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"CCS Office\":[{\"Name\":\"Woodstock\",\"CCS Description\":null,\"BranchType\":\"Sub CFS Office\",\"Status\":\"Active\",\"Circle\":\"NJ\"}]}]"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "thing": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It really helped.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and this is how I resolved the issue.

I passed the value of Response as a string to lookup activity which calls a stored procedure in Azure SQL. The stored procedure parses the string using Json_value and return the individual key, value as a row. Now output of lookup activity can be accessed directly from preceding activities.